# "Uncaught TypeError: login.addEventListener is not a function" error showing , why?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code, the `index.html` file and the `login.js` file. Why am I getting this error? I am stuck on this.

```js
const username = document.getElementsByClassName('username');
const password = document.getElementsByClassName('password');
const login = document.getElementsByClassName('login');


function validate(){
    if ((username = 'abc') && (password = "1234")){
        alert("login succ`enter code here`esfull");
    }

}

login.addEventListener('click', validate);
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Enter Username and Password</h1>
    <div>
    <label> Username: </label>
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <br>
    <label> Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="password">
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="login" value="Log In" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: You also need to learn the difference between https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality